# how to add multiple wallets on Payable?

Tags: solidity

the code part was originally like this:

```
function swapAndSendToFee (uint256 tokens) private {
uint256 ethToSend = swapTokensForEth(tokens);

if (ethToSend > 0)
payable(_projectWallet).transfer(ethToSend);

}
```

but I wanted to add an extra wallet and I defined it earlier all good, but now it doesn't sell:

```
function swapAndSendToFee (uint256 tokens) private {
uint256 ethToSend = swapTokensForEth(tokens);

if (ethToSend > 0)
payable(_projectWallet).transfer(ethToSend);
payable(_marketingWallet).transfer(ethToSend);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in the second snippet:

1. A condition without a block only applies to the next line. So your current code could be also written as this:

```
if (ethToSend > 0) {
    payable(_projectWallet).transfer(ethToSend);
}
payable(_marketingWallet).transfer(ethToSend);
```

I'm assuming you also wanted to wrap the `transfer()` functions in a block, so that the condition looks like this:

```
if (ethToSend > 0) {
    payable(_projectWallet).transfer(ethToSend);
    payable(_marketingWallet).transfer(ethToSend);
}
```

2. In the second snippet, you're trying to transfer twice as much ETH from the contract, compared to the first snippet. It's possible that **the contract doesn't have sufficient funds** to perform both transfers.

First you transfer `ethToSend` amount to the `_projectWallet`, and then you also transfer the same `ethToSend` amount to the `_marketingWallet`

If you want to split the amount between the two wallets, you can perform a basic arithmetic operation:

```
payable(_projectWallet).transfer(ethToSend / 2);
payable(_marketingWallet).transfer(ethToSend / 2);
```